# VSCode couldn't stop debug by debugger tab C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

This project is Blazorwasm -- hosted.

I cannot click stop or restart debugger tab. I have to reopen VS Code for work again and I cannot debug code in VS Code. I cannot set breakpoint for check. I just can run from `dotnet run` or `dotnet watch run` How to resolve this problem.

[image]

This is my launch.json. Is this correct?

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch and Debug Standalone Blazor WebAssembly App",
            "type": "blazorwasm",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Server"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure which browser you're using, but see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72037574) for working config.

Comment: I have tried to fix my browser, reinstall .Netcore, reinstall vscode, reinstall vscode extension such as omnisharp,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.VsCode.BlazorWasmDebuggingExtension

Comment: I feel your pain man, it's very buggy right now. I've had all the same problems. The solution I posted works for me, but maybe I was just lucky. Good luck!

Comment: There are an [Issue on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/143269)